# Node.js async await won't work with db query

Tags: node.js

```
app.get('/someApi', async (req, res) => {
    var a = await SomeMethod();
})
```

```
function SomeMethod() 
{
 let sql = 'SELECT * FROM someTable'
    var query = db.query(sql, (err, results) =>{
        if(err)
        {
            throw err
        }
       if(results ... some logic)
        {
          return true;
        }
       else{
          return false;
       }
    })
}
```

If i call SomeMethod from someApi it will pass the line and say that var a = undefined instead of true or false.
I need to get a response, true/false before going to next line after var a in someApi.

Comment: Also if i return true/false outside of db.query it will work fine. Is a problem in that db.query. Also if i return true/false without results ... some logic it will behave the same, skip lane and says var a = undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the callback function to a promise and then use await on it.

```
function SomeMethod() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM someTable'
        db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            if (results) {
                resolve(true);
            }
            else {
                resolve(false);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```
app.get('/someApi', async (req, res) => {
    var a = await SomeMethod();
});
```

Comment: Works fine with Promise, thanks!!

Comment: @Seb. Glad it hepped. You can accept the answer if it works.

Comment: u answered so fast that i couldnt accept the answer in less than 10mins as the stackoverflow rulles says

Comment: @Seb Oh, that is something I never heard about :\